# In Mac OS X El Capitan, is it still possible to change the color of the bubbles in Messages?

Tags: macos, messages, settings, preferences

I have looked through Preferences, System Preferences, even looked at a couple of 3rd-party apps.  I could find nothing of use.

So is it still possible to change the color of chat bubbles (and text) in Messages, like you could in Mavericks, or not?